# Eliminar una posición de una matriz y reemplazarla por 0. C#

Tags: c#, array

estoy empezando a programar y la verdad es que no tengo ni idea de como sacar este ejercicio adelante. Necesito que el usuario escoga una posición de una matriz [3,3] y que elimine la posición reemplazándola por un 0. Agradecería una ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

```
int[,] matriz2 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 } };

 for (int i = 0; i < matriz2.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz2.GetLength(1); j++)
    Console.Write(matriz2[i, j] + (" "));      
 }

 Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
```

Hasta aquí bien, muestro la matriz por pantalla, pero ahora viene lo difícil y no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, por Internet solo he encontrado formas de hacerlo en un array de una sola dimensión,he intentado adaptar el algoritmo al de una matriz pero no me sale. Un saludo.

Comment: pero eliminar no es lo mismo que reemplazar, porque si solo se trata de asignar valores ceros es una cosa, pero si quiere eliminar la posicion rquiere redimensionarla

Answer (score 2):

No se si entendí bien, pero sería solicitar al usuario la posicion que desea eliminar e igualar el arreglo en esa posición a 0, suponiendo que ingresó 1 y 2:

```
 matriz2[1, 2] = 0;
```